# In place modification through recursion

Tags: python, recursion, depth-first-search, list-manipulation

Regarding the following leetcode problem #210, I tried to create a more lean DFS algorithm by doing in-place modifications to the stack as follows:

```
numCourses = 2
prerequisites = [[1,0]]

class Solution(object):
    def findOrder(self, numCourses, prerequisites):
        """
        :type numCourses: int
        :type prerequisites: List[List[int]]
        :rtype: List[int]
        """
        
        stack = []
        self.dfs(prerequisites, 0, stack)
        return stack.reverse()
    
    def dfs(self, prereqs, node, stack):
        for courses in prereqs:
            if node == courses[1] and courses[0] not in stack:
                self.dfs(prereqs, courses[0], stack)
        stack.append(node)
```

However, when I return the stack in `findOrder` function, it returns an empty list. Even when I am debugging, it shows that the stack is updated with the values `[0,1]` but when I return it, it returns the empty list.

I was wondering if there are any implications I may be missing when trying to do in-place modifications to lists via recursion.

Comment: `stack.reverse()` returns `None`, not the reversed stack.

Comment: It can't be returning an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to return your `stack` list instead of `stack.reverse()`. as pointed out in the comments `.reverse()` returns `None` instead of the reversed list.